# Convert/Create a List (Of String) array to class or function

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, list

I have this code that phases a text file, formats it, and then creates a List(Of String) for each new line. Now what I want to do is create a class out of that List(Of String) so it can be accessed from anywhere in the program  , and be able to pass it an integer parameter and it should return the string value of the integer index of the List(Of Strings). **(I guess not sure if that's the right approach??)** A bit confusing **

So for example: 
say I have the following

```
     Dim gcodelist As New List(Of String)

    Dim lines As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    For Each l As String In lines
        gcodelist.Add(l)
    Next
```

I want to be able to turn that code into a class so that in Main sub() I can just call for example

```
   Sub Main() 
   MsgBox(Gcodeblock(5))
   End Sub
```

And it should print gcodelist(5) of the List (Of String) array to the msg box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class Gcodeblock, with an indexer (the 'Item' method):

```
Public Class Gcodeblock
    Private gcodelist As New List(Of String)

    Public Sub New(ByVal text As String)
        Dim lines As String() = text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        For Each l As String In lines
            gcodelist.Add(l)
        Next
    End Sub

    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As String
        Get
            Return gcodelist(index)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

and use it like this:

```
Dim GcodeblockInstance = New Gcodeblock(yourText)
MsgBox(GcodeblockInstance(0))
```

My example uses a readonly indexer, but there's no reason you couldn't make it writable (remove the 'ReadOnly' keyword and add a 'Set' block).

Or you can inherit from List(Of String):

```
Public Class Gcodeblock
    Inherits List(Of String)

    Public Sub New(ByVal text As String)
        Dim lines As String() = text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        For Each l As String In lines
            MyBase.Add(l)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: More about this class. I been working with it for a while now but just found out that it doesn't inherit the generic collections properties. Ex. Gcodeblock.count or Gcodeblock.(x) where x can be any property. Any insight on this matter?

Comment: You can add your own 'Count' method. I'm not sure what you mean by "Gcodeblock.(x) where x can be any property".

Comment: Gcodeblock.(x) meaning gcodeblock.add ,gcodeblock.foreach etc basically inherit everything you can do to a regular List (Of Strings)

Comment: In that case, you may be better off inheriting from List(Of String) - I've added a section to the bottom of my answer which shows how to do this. You don't even need your own 'Item' method either.

Comment: Thanks i'll try it out will I still need to add the Default Public Properties to the class or not?

Comment: You don't need to add a Default Item property - unless you want it to work differently than the List one.

Comment: Nice! Thanks again just what I was looking for.